# Cannot put the 1 sign for author affiliation in latex on wiley-NDJ v2, how to fix that?

Tags: article, author, affiliation, paper, wiley-article

I am trying to write author affiliation next to each author name in WILEYNDJ format, here is my code

```
  \documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\articletype{Article Type}%



\begin{document}

\title{TITLE}

\author[1]{JOHN SMITH*}

\author[1]{REBECCA JOHNSON}

\author[1]{BRAD LARSON}

\author[1]{JESSICA SAMSON}


\authormark{AUTHOR`1 \textsc{et al}}


\address[1]{\orgdiv{UNIVERSITY},
\orgaddress{\state{CITY}, \country{COUNTRY}}}



\corres{*Corresponding author name, This is sample corresponding address. \email{john.smith@gmail.com}}



\abstract[Summary]{TEST}



\maketitle





\end{document}
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, the number 1 does not appear next to each author name, how can we fix this?
[image]

I am also using the WileyNJD-v2.cls file that you can find in the AMA-lato.zip file that you can find in the following link

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/20477481/homepage/la_tex_class_file.html
Alternatively, I am sharing with you the project where I encounter the problem

https://www.overleaf.com/5631135849vymtsktmsjpr

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The superscript numbers appear when you have more of one address defined.

[image: d]

The style of the journal suppress the superscripts is all authors share the same address. (Which makes sense)

Use only `\address{\orgdiv{UNIVERSITY}, \orgaddress{\state{CITY}, \country{COUNTRY}}}`

[image: c]

(1) The code needs to be compiled with `xelatex` or `lualatex` to use the defined fonts.

(2) `WileyNJD-v2.cls` downloaded from [Wiley Online Library](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/14678640/AMA-stix-1521468608820.zip). (version  2017/06/23 v0.2 )

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[AMA,LATO1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

\articletype{Article Type}%

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author[1]{JOHN SMITH*}

\author[2]{REBECCA JOHNSON}

\author[2]{BRAD LARSON}

\author[2]{JESSICA SAMSON}

\authormark{AUTHOR ONE \textsc{et al}}

\address[1]{\orgdiv{UNIVERSITY}, \orgaddress{\state{CITY}, \country{COUNTRY}}}

\address[2]{\orgdiv{UNIVERSITY2}, \orgaddress{\state{CITY2}, \country{COUNTRY}}} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\corres{*Corresponding author name, This is sample corresponding address. \email{john.smith@gmail.com}}

\abstract[Summary]{TEST}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```